# MySQL - Select differently

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this query, which selects a distinct value for a column, but I need something else in that query too. I need it to fetch a different row associated with the main select.

Let me illustrate...

This is my query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ' . DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_free_result($result);

return $rows;
```

As you see it returns this query returns the DISTINCT of user_id.

[image: My table]

If I use a function like this in a double foreach loop created using the return of the query above:

```
public function get_donor_status($user_id)
{
    global $db;

    $sql = 'SELECT payment_status FROM ' .DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE .
           " WHERE user_id = '" . (int) $user_id . "'";
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

    $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
    $payment_status = $row['payment_status'];

    $db->sql_freeresult($result);

    return $payment_status;
}
```

This function would return **Completed** for user_id 2, but I want it to say **Pending** instead. How would I change my query so it returns the last value for the corresponding user_id?

If I'm not clear enough, please let me know so I can reexplain.

Answer (score 5):

Just select the last row for the user:

```
"SELECT payment_status FROM " . DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE . " WHERE user_id = '" . (int) $user_id . "' ORDER BY donation_id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$sql = 'SELECT payment_status FROM ' .DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE .
           " WHERE user_id = '" . (int) $user_id . "' ORDER BY donation_id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get everything in one SQL statement, no need for a double loop:

```
SELECT
    user_id, payment_status
FROM
    DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE t1
WHERE
    donation_id = (select max(donation_id) from DONATION_SECURITY_TABLE t2 WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id)
ORDER BY
    user_id
```